# Is there a simple way to persist command history in Vim/Neovim?

Tags: command-history

Is there an option I can switch on the init.vim config file to let me keep command history between vim sessions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I get you right, it should be persisted by default.

Use `:<C-f>` or `q:` to open command line with command history

[image]

Vim command history is kept in `viminfo` file (`:h viminfo`). Neovim uses different thing (`:h shada`).

Comment: You are correct, my mistake was to alternate between Vim and Neovim.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default location of `shada-file` (history) to fix the location of this file by:

```
set shada+='1000,n/opt/my.shada
```

You can choose any location for the shada-file. Don't forget to give the user permission to this file:

```
sudo chown username:username /opt/my.shada
```

If you want more history, change `1000`.